# URL regex that does and does not contain exact word

Tags: python, html, regex, url, uri

I have this line to check for URLs in html soup:

```
^http[s]?:\/\/[^:\/\s]+[^#?\s()]+/
```

Now I have two words to check for. How should I modify this line to contain FOO and NOT contain BAR anywhere in the line?

I want all links like http://bazfoo.com/something/else and not http://quxfoobar.com/something/else

Adding (?:foo) anywhere breaks the expression, so does negative lookahead pattern (?!bar).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
^(?!.*bar)(?=.*foo).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xgG9AO/3

Comment: Now better, but how can I also exclude non-ur characters like parentheses, spaces, etc?